# How to get the Sum of Length of Body Documents

Tags: apex, roll-up-summary

How can I get the sum of all the length of select Options document
I only want the value of the Selected Documents.

```
docNames = new List<SelectOption>();   

for (Document d : [
    SELECT Id, Name , Body, BodyLength
    FROM Document
    WHERE (FolderId =: UserInfo.getUserId() OR FolderId =: '00lG0000001bBXb')
    AND ContentType = 'application/pdf'
]){
    docNames.add(
        new SelectOption(d.Id,d.Name + ' - ' + String.valueof(d.BodyLength) + ' bytes')
    );
    for (Integer i=0 ; i<= docNames.size() ; i++){
        docNames.BodyLength[i] ;
    }
}
```

Then I want do a try and catch so I dont let the user submit PDF files that sums up more than 5MB

```
try {
    if(d.BodyLength/1048576 >= 5) {
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(
            ApexPages.severity.INFO,
            'The size of the file you are trying to upload is more than 5 MB. Please select another file.')
        );
        System.debug(' size > 5mb');
    }
}
catch(Exception pokemon){ // gotta catch em all!
    System.debug('ERROR:' + e);
}
```

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @AdrianLarson You cant submit more than 5 MB of documents to any outside API from salesforce, I wanna catch that before sending that out by using the bodylenght. I get the value on each document now, I just need to add them up together, I dotn know how to make that for loop to add up bodylenght

Comment: What type of `Exception` are you actually expecting? Are you having any problems with your code? You don't actually ask a question as is.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I want to be able to stop and bring them back to same page and say your file needs to be smaller than 5 MB, is there away to calculate the size of file as they are selecting it?

Comment: But why the `try`/`catch`? It seems completely irrelevant to what you are trying to accomplish. A good question will only contain what is relevant in addition to making the intention clear. You are also missing a lot of context. Is this on a `Visualforce Page`? How are they being selected in the first place?

Comment: Don't include 'body' in the soql as you will blow up heap

Comment: @crop1645 that is what is happening right now, I get Heap error

Comment: @AdrianLarson try and catch was the solution I thought I can use to send an error to the user and stop them from submission if its more than 5mb

Comment: I think you are confusing `catch` and `throw`. `addMessage` doesn't throw anything.

Comment: heap errors can't be caught; hence why you shouldn't include `body` in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do. It looks like you are building up a List of SelectOptions and then also trying to track the Body size of all those documents.

One likely cause of heap size issues here is retrieving the actual Body of the Document records in Apex when you only need to know the `BodyLength`.

Try something like:

```
List<SelectOption> docNames = new List<SelectOption>();
long totalBodyLength = 0;
Id exFolderId = '00lG0000001bBXb';

for (Document d : [SELECT Id, Name, BodyLength
                   FROM Document
                   WHERE (FolderId = :UserInfo.getUserId() OR FolderId = :exFolderId)
                       AND ContentType = 'application/pdf'] ){

    if(d.BodyLength >= 5 * 1048576) {
        // Exclude large documents that would exceed the Heap size
        // Could probably handle via the WHERE clause
        continue;
        // Note that in theory it should even be possible to create a Document > 5MB
    }

    docNames.add(
        new SelectOption(d.Id, d.Name + ' - ' + String.valueof(d.BodyLength) + ' bytes')
    );
    totalBodyLength += d.BodyLength;
}
```

Consider using `Limits.getHeapSize()` and `Limits.getLimitHeapSize()` to check for current and available heap. As Adrian comments, you won't be able to use the entire heap for the document body.

Comment: Thank you for respond, Here what I am doing now, I am getting the d.bodylength to show on each document in visual force page, then I do Regular Expression on Javascript and try to sum up every single one that has been selected. do you think that is reasonable way to calculate how big are the total of selected PDF files (Document)?

Comment: So your goal is to prevent users from selecting more documents than can held in the heap at any one time?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do. I am sending all files outside of salesforce into my own server make them as one big file and getting them returned, but if its bigger than 5 MB or 6MB i cant remember, salesforce will throw heap error on page

Comment: How are you sending the documents? There are ways to increase the heap size. For instance, there is a [pilot](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enhanced_future_overview.htm) on getting a larger heap size on @future calls.

Comment: If you can get the document ids out into asynchronous Apex you will get a 12 MB head size. You will still be limited to Documents of 5MB in size for the result.

Comment: my server only handles one byte array, I cant send multiple . 5 MB is more than enough if I can some how show user that they have Exceeded their maximum . Here is what I am doing in the other side, which I still have issues with displaying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348886/javascript-for-loop-not-adding-up-correctly

Comment: @DanielBallinger The remaining heap size will be slightly less because you are using some. Might be worth mentioning how to compare against the *remaining* heap space.

Comment: @bez Javascript on the client should work to validate the total size of the selection. You might want to double check the totals when you return the selections to the controller.